# Dynamic Routing in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to create duplicate view, viewmodel using exiting in Aurelia Framework.

For example, I have an existing route,

```js
{ route: "pageA", moduleId: "views/pageA", nav: true, title: "PageA" }
```

Now I want to create new route dynamically, for example:

```js
{ route: "pageA1", moduleId: "views/pageA", nav: false, title: "PageA1" }
```

I am using the below code to solve my problem

```js
this.router.addRoute({ route: "pageA1", moduleId: "views/pageA", nav: true, title: "PageA1" });
this.router.refreshNavigation();`
```

The new routes are getting added in the route collection object but navigation is not happening(`this.router.navigate('PageA1'`).

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue and achieve dynamic routes in the application.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in your question you wrote

> but navigation is not happening `this.router.navigate('PageA1')`.

Shouldn't that be a lower-case `P`? eg:

```js
this.router.navigate('pageA1')
```

Comment: I think, I made a typo while posting the question.